# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined is not a function using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am a beginner of nodejs programming.while i am adding the records on postman i got the error of
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined. what i tried so far i attached below.please give the soloution for it correct.

**routes**

```
router.route('/user/create').post(userController.createUserControllerFn);
```

**userController**

```
var createUserControllerFn = async (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);

    var status = await userService.cretaeUserDBService(req.body);
    console.log("*************************");
    console.log(status);
    console.log("*************************");

    if (status) {
        res.send({ "status": true, "message": "User created successfully" });
    } else {
        res.send({ "status": false, "message": "Error creating user" });
    }


}
```

**userServices**

```
module.exports.cretaeUserDBService = (userDetais) => {


   return new Promise(function myFn(resolve, reject) {

       var userModelData = new userModel();

       userModelData.first_name = userDetais.first_name;
       userModelData.last_name = userDetais.last_name;
       userModelData.email = userDetais.email;

       var encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(userDetais.password);
       userModelData.password = encrypted;

       userModelData.save(function resultHandle(error, result) {

           if (error) {
               reject(false);
           } else {
               resolve(true);
           }
       });

   });

}
```

**userModel**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({

    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});


// var userModel = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)


module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Comment: In your code, it is `userService.cretaeUserDBService`, is it a typo?

Comment: you are tell that to change module.exports.cretaeUserDBService  to userService.cretaeUserDBService

Comment: you can try this.

Comment: i tried again i got the error was UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

Comment: i changed error